# Would a user be required to re-compile, if only non-virtual, non-overloading member functions were added to a class?

Tags: c++

This is just a theoretical question. I've run into a similar problem in the COM world and wondered if this is also applicable in the C++ world. I'm also aware that I could avoid this problem with the Pimpl Idiom.

Suppose I had a class A version 1. I shipped the header file and the library file to the clients.

Then one day, I updated A by adding some functions (which are not virtual and not overloading). Class A is now version 2.

Suppose version 2 was compiled in the same environment and settings as version 1.

My understanding is in the new library file, class A's size and vtable will not be changed. Also since no overloading functions are added, the clients will not call the wrong function. As a result, users are not required to recompile their code.

Are there any pitfalls for this assumption?

Comment: Besides the obvious: this is a violation of the ODR, and that in turns means *Undefined Behavior*, there's probably nothing wrong... But this cannot really be answered in general, as it might depend on the compiler and platform.

Comment: I agree with David, the problem in answering this question is that binary compatibility is implementation-dependent, it's down to the C++ ABI used. So to answer for C++ in general, you have to answer the question "is there any C++ ABI, anywhere, ever, for which this is an incompatibility, or will one be created in between me answering and someone in future using that answer?". Which is a difficult kind of question to answer, no matter how unlikely it is that anyone will implement non-virtual functions other than as just another symbol mapping to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no pitfalls that I'm aware. The concept you're describing is called binary compatibility.

Because version 2 of class A is still binary compatible (as far as I'm aware) with version 1 of class A, then no recompile is required. The KDE Techbase article has a decent set of guidelines (with examples) to follow for maintaining binary compatibility.

http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++